# How to Insert Literal Text from a Keybinding, without Triggering Substitutions

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I am new to VSCode, and I have a regular need to make keyboard learn sequences, which seems to not be a thing in the VSCode IDE.  Following the advice of several sites, I got an extension for marcos and have been making custom keybindings as a workaround.

This has been pretty rough going because apparently, the only master list of commands is in the Keyboard Shortcuts tab, and secondly there is little to no documentation on these hundreds of individual commands.  (In particular, I have not been able to find *any* master list of the arguments accepted by each command).

In any event, I have had some success making the custom keybindings that I need, however, one particular problem that I keep running into is that the only way that I can see to insert specific literal text is with the *"type"* command, however, this apparently really does *try to type each character* and lets the keyboard style, etc. substitutions auto-fire.  I do not need or want this, and I need to be able to stop it, or find some other (practical) way to insert my literal text without *any* reinterpretation, substitution or other keybindings triggering (or whatever facility is doing this).

Here is my current keybinding command set:

```
    "EditLitPropToGet": [
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "get "}},
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorRightSelect",
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "() { return "}},
        "cursorEnd",
        "cursorWordStartLeft",
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "; }"}},
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorWordStartLeft"
    ]
```

The purpose of this is, when positioned at the beginning of the first word in this line:

```
referenceGravity: this.surfaceGravity * (this.radius**2),
```

to then turn it into this line:

```
get referenceGravity() { this.surfaceGravity * (this.radius**2); },
```

This works fine up until it gets to the second `type` command:

```
        {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "() { return "}},
```

Before this runs the line looks like this:

`get referenceGravity`**:** `this.surfaceGravity * (this.radius**2),`

with the colon character selected.  What the `type` command above is supposed to do is this:

```
get referenceGravity() { return  this.surfaceGravity * (this.radius**2),
```

But what actually happens is this:

```
get referenceGravity() { return }) this.surfaceGravity * (this.radius**2),
```

Clearly, this is because it is seeing the `type` text as keyboard input and is triggering the style closures for "()" and "{}".

### How can I just insert literal text?

To be clear, I am not looking to also have to define a custom snippet everytime I want to do this, or to have to pre-load the paste-buffer, I need these keybindings to be self-contained.

Nor do I want to blindly en-masse disable all extensions, stylings, etc at the beginning, if that means that I have to blindly enable them all at the end.  I am willing to try something *like* that, but if I already have something disabled, it shouldn't then re-enable it because it doesn't know what was previously enabled/disabled.  If it's just disabling/enabling one specific setting, that's fine, I can live with correcting that as needed.

---

Just to update this, I have accepted the answer by @Mark because it gave a solution for this specific case.  However, as to the general question: "*How can I insert literal text?*", I believe that I finally understand what folks have been telling:  You can use `insertSnippet` to insert literal text, you just have to escape things that might be seen as Textmate/RegEx commands ("`$`", and "`` ` ``" with "`\`").  So this should work:

```
    "EditLitPropToGet": [
        {"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", 
            "args": {"snippet": "get "}},
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorRightSelect",
        {"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", 
            "args": {"snippet": "() { return "}},
        "cursorEnd",
        "cursorWordStartLeft",
        {"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", 
            "args": {"snippet": "; }"}},
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorWordRight",
        "cursorWordStartLeft"
    ]
```

Comment: I'm just guessing, but try `"command": "editor.action.insertSnippet", "args": {"snippet": "your_text_here"},`. Also, what extension do you use to execute several commands with a single hotkey?

Comment: It looks like you need to disable `Editor: Auto Closing Brackets`.  Also I wouldn't suggest using the `macros` extension - it isn't synchronous and is not maintained.  Look at its issues.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Wouldn't that try to run a snippet with that name?  Oh, and the extension I am using is "macros" by geddski (`geddski.macros` is the extension identifier).

Comment: @Mark Hmm, I thought that it was the prior incarnation that had the problems.  Can you suggest an alternative?  Also, I will try your suggestion shortly, but I really would still like to know how to just insert literal text.

Comment: @Mark Wait, I don't know how you disable a setting from a keybinding command?

Comment: @RBarryYoung There are forks, like [this one](https://github.com/ctf0/macros). *"Wouldn't that try to run a snippet with that name?"* No, that should insert the text you give to it.

Comment: `geddski.macros` is the one that isn't properly `promise-ified`.  I use `multi-command` which I like.  One of the splits from `macros` fixed the problem but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: No, you cannot generally alter a setting in a macro unless that setting happens to have an associated shortcut with command, which some do.  Personally, I would just make your whole command one snippet transform.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat OK, I will try the insertSnippet, and I will change to ctf0.macros as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to show you how the snippet transform version, this keybinding:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+1",             // or whatever you want
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
    "args": {
      "snippet": "get ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^(\\w*):(.*),$/$1() {$2/}; },"
  }
},
```

produces your desired output.  You do have to select the line first, but that could be automated inside a macro very easily (or just bind the `cursorLineEndSelect` command.  That macro would have just two commands: `cursorLineEndSelect` and insert the above snippet.

---

Example macro using multi-command, I don't know the syntax for `ctf0.macros` which does look more powerful:

```
 "multiCommand.commands": [

     {
      "command": "multiCommand.yourMacroNameHere",
      "interval": 2000,
      "sequence": [
        "cursorEnd",
        "cursorHomeSelect",
        {
          "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
          "args": {
            "snippet": "get ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^\\s*(\\w*):(.*),$/$1() {$2/}; },"
          }
        },
        "cursorDown"
      ]
    },
```

The `interval` is unecessary in your case, just there to watch it work -it can be commented out.  The cursor can be anywhere on the line containing the line you want to transform.  It doesn't need to be pre-selected, the macro will do that for you.

I would reload vscode (through the command palette) after making these changes just in case.

Again, the demo looks slow but that is just to demonstrate the individual steps with the `interval` option.  Otherwise it is instantaneous.

[image: snippet transform]

---

If you want to use your macro, then use the `insertSnippet` command in place of that one `type` command:

```
    // {"command": "type", "args": {"text": "() { return "}},
    {
      "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
      "args": {
        "snippet": "() { return }"
      }
    },
```

that does not seem to trigger the auto-close braces.  Snippets do require escaping more characters than a `type` command does though - but not in your case.

Comment: What's the stuff after "get ..."?  Is that some kind of regEx search and replace for snippets?

Comment: Yes, snippets allow you to do "transforms" in this case on the built-in variable `TM_SELECTED_TEXT`. See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variable-transforms.  you can parse that variable with regex and then do various things with the capture groups.  It can be a very powerful tool - I have answered a lot of SO questions on it where the alternative would be to write an extension.

Comment: I am trying this out and am running into a problem.  As long as it is the last command in my macro, it works fine.  But I want it to also move to the next line, and when I add a command to do that ("cursorWordRight") instead of transforming the selected line, it just adds a new line after it with `get ; },`.  Do I need to explicitly terminate the snippet action or something?

Comment: You may wish to check out the extension "multi command" as well.

Comment: I modified the answer to show the sequence of commands  -  your macro syntax is probably different.  I'll post a demo after lunch :>}

Comment: OK, I'll upgrade my macro facility to something new, and then if problems persist, post a new question for that problem.  One thing that I would like to ask, I am not proficient in RegExp so this answer is overly specific for me.  Is there a straightforward way with this approach to *just* insert literal text?  I can figure out everything else with the editor commands.  If I could use insertSnippet to insert literal text, then that would be a reusable answer for me (even I can figure out how to change literal text in a RegEx).

Comment: I did install multiCommand, and it is working great, even with commands after the insertSnippet/RegExp.  The `interval:` is a great feature for macro debugging!

Comment: As @Holy said in the first comment, try the `insertSnippet` command in a macro - I edited the answer - it doesn't appear to trigger the auto-close of braces.